# How can I check if a file exists on a remote server using PHP?

Tags: php

How can I check if a specific file exists on a remote server using PHP via FTP connections?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I used this, a bit easier:

```
// the server you wish to connect to - you can also use the server ip ex. 107.23.17.20
        $ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";

// set up a connection to the server we chose or die and show an error
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
        ftp_login($conn_id,"ftpserver_username","ftpserver_password");

// check if a file exist
        $path = "/SERVER_FOLDER/"; //the path where the file is located

        $file = "file.html"; //the file you are looking for

        $check_file_exist = $path.$file; //combine string for easy use

        $contents_on_server = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path); //Returns an array of filenames from the specified directory on success or FALSE on error. 

// Test if file is in the ftp_nlist array
        if (in_array($check_file_exist, $contents_on_server)) 
        {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "I found ".$check_file_exist." in directory : ".$path;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<br>";
            echo $check_file_exist." not found in directory : ".$path;  
        };

        // output $contents_on_server, shows all the files it found, helps for debugging, you can use print_r() as well
        var_dump($contents_on_server);

// remember to always close your ftp connection
        ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Functions used: (thanks to middaparka)

1. Login using [ftp_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)
2. Get the remote file list via [ftp_nlist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php)
3. Use [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to see if the file was present in the array

Comment: About commented problems: se [cache-solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22196769/287948).

Comment: What if you have hundreds of thousands of files or more? Downloading the list of all files is not the best option.

Comment: @kintsukuroi If you have that many files you can do a few things - 1. Drill down the folders and search per folder. 2. Cache the list of files on your folder and use that list. 3. If you are hosted on a unix box, you can do a bash command `ls` and write that to a json file and search through that. 4. This is probably not the solution for you, this was written years ago to search through small sites for a specific file in the root directory.

Comment: @Drmzindec 1.- All files are in a single folder. 2.- Best solution is ftp_size. 3.- I appreciate your time, good luck.

Answer (score 59):

Some suggestions:

- Use `ftp_size`, which returns -1 if it doesn't exist: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-size.php
- Use `fopen`, e.g. fopen("ftp://user:password@example.com/somefile.txt", "r")
- Use `ftp_nlist`, check to see if the filename you want is in the list: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Comment: `fopen()` and `file_exits()` are elegant, but [need some "error checking"](http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to avoid "false negatives". About `ftp_nlist` and @Andrew comment, I am including a "cache solution" here as more one answer.

Answer (score 22):

Just check the size of a file. If the size is `-1`, it doesn't exist, so:

```
$file_size = ftp_size($ftp_connection, "example.txt");

if ($file_size != -1) {
    echo "File exists";

} else {
    echo "File does not exist";
}
```

If the size is `0`, the file does exist, it's just 0 bytes.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-size.php)

Comment: Sorry, it is an old question but people still come here for an answer. :) +1 for question!

Comment: be wary with this. on (some?) ftp servers, ftp_size() on a directory name also returns -1 (whether or not it exists).  I understand the implication is that you would only run this on a file, but it's worth noting this limitation.

Answer (score 5):

A general solution would be to:

1. Login using [ftp_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)
2. Navigate to the relevant directory via [ftp_chdir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-chdir.php)
3. Get the remote file list via [ftp_nlist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php) or [ftp_rawlist](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php)
4. Use [in_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to see if the file was present in the array returned by ftp_rawlist

That said, you could potentially simply use [file_exists](http://www.php.net/file_exists) if you have the relevant URL wrappers available. (See the [PHP FTP and FTPS protocols and wrappers manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) for more information.)

Comment: this can be slow, if there is a big file list (5000+)

Comment: slow and inefficient for large dirs, same as previous

Comment: @Andrew Including my `file_exists` suggestion, or are you just on a petty downvoting mission?

Comment: Not sure about these comments. Is it better to manipulate a 5000 array or make 5000 `ftp_size()`? Do a bench with this solution and compare it with individual network calls (`ft_size()`, etc). Depends of latency, network congestion, etc. php7.3+ arrays are now faster. However, instead of `in_array()`, do an `array_flip(ftp_nlist(...))`, then check if present with `isset()`. A lot faster!

Answer (score 5):

This is an optimization of @JohanPretorius solution, and an answer for comments about "slow and inefficient for large dirs" of @Andrew and other: if you need more than one "file_exist checking", this function is a optimal solution.

### `ftp_file_exists()` caching last folder

```
  function ftp_file_exists(
      $file, // the file that you looking for
      $path = "SERVER_FOLDER",   // the remote folder where it is
      $ftp_server = "ftp.example.com", //Server to connect to
      $ftp_user = "ftpserver_username", //Server username
      $ftp_pwd = "ftpserver_password", //Server password
      $useCache = 1  // ALERT: do not $useCache when changing the remote folder $path.
  ){

      static $cache_ftp_nlist = array();
      static $cache_signature = '';

      $new_signature = "$ftp_server/$path";

      if(!$useCache || $new_signature!=$cache_signature) 
          {
              $useCache = 0;
              //$new_signature = $cache_signature;
              $cache_signature = $new_signature;
               // setup the connection
               $conn_id         = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Error connecting $ftp_server");
               $ftp_login           = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user, $ftp_pwd);
               $cache_ftp_nlist = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);

               if ($cache_ftp_nlist===FALSE)die("erro no ftp_nlist");
          }

        //$check_file_exist = "$path/$file";
        $check_file_exist = "$file";

        if(in_array($check_file_exist, $cache_ftp_nlist)) 
            {
                echo "Found: ".$check_file_exist." in folder: ".$path;
            } 
        else 
            {
                echo "Not Found: ".$check_file_exist." in folder: ".$path;  
            };
        // use for debuging: var_dump($cache_ftp_nlist);
        if(!$useCache) ftp_close($conn_id);
    } //function end

    //Output messages
    echo ftp_file_exists("file1-to-find.ext"); // do FTP
    echo ftp_file_exists("file2-to-find.ext"); // using cache
    echo ftp_file_exists("file3-to-find.ext"); // using cache
    echo ftp_file_exists("file-to-find.ext","OTHER_FOLDER"); // do FTP
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ftp_nlist to list all the files on the remote server. Then you should search into the result array to check if the file what you was looking for exists.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Answer (score -3):

The code has been written by: @Drmzindec should be change a little:

```
if (in_array($check_file_exist, $contents_on_server))
```

to

```
if (in_array($file, $contents_on_server))
```

Comment: Why? There really is no reason the change the variable name, its named in a manner that is easy to read, a variable name can be anything you want. This adds nothing to the solution.