# Create diectory (ftp_mkdir) only if files exist

Tags: php, ftp, directory

I currently have a program that connects to an ftp directory, if it finds csv files, runs a script, then after the script has run on the files, it creates a back up folder with the date and moves the csv files to this newly created back up folder in the ftp directory.

However, if there are no csv files in the root directory, I do not want a backup folder to be created, as there are no files to move. I know the solution is probably really simple but I cannot seem to figure it out!

```
 logMessage("Creating backups");
    $ftp_connection = @ftp_connect($ftp_url, $ftp_port, 6000);
    if(!@ftp_login($ftp_connection, $ftp_username, $ftp_password )) {
       logMessage("Could not connect to FTP: [$ftp_url], with Username: [$ftp_username], and Password: [$ftp_password]");
        die();
    }

$date = date('Y_m_d_(His)');

$newBackup = $ftp_root."/".$ftp_backup."backup_$date";

if (ftp_mkdir($ftp_connection, $newBackup)) {
    logMessage ("Successfully created [$newBackup\n]");

    foreach($filesToProcess as $file){
        $pathData = pathinfo($file);      
        if(isset($pathData['extension']) && $pathData['extension'] == 'csv'){

            if(!@ftp_rename($ftp_connection,
                    $ftp_root.'/'.$file,
                    $newBackup."/".$file)
            ){
                logMessage("Unable to move file: $file")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852767/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-on-a-remote-server-using-php

Comment: where does `$filestoprocess` come from?

Comment: sorry. files to process is: $filesToProcess = ftp_nlist($ftp_connection, ".");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used, foreach($filesToProcess as $file) ,so in $filesToProcess it's array of files. you can use, count($filesToProcess) first count number of files, then if count>0 execute code.

Comment: I knew it was simple, think I just spent too long programming that day... thanks. I just had to take into account any existing directories count > count($dir) e.g. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// $csv = your checks for string ending to .csv
$ftp_files = ftp_nlist($ftp_connection, ".");
foreach ($ftp_files = $files) {
   if ($files = $csv) {
     // makedir
```

maybe something like this in very basic syntax. ftp_nlist returns an array of all files in a particular directory.