# How to access files outside ftp server using file_exists

Tags: php

I want to monitor if the reference data is already uploaded or existing in our server.
This is what I've tried..

```
<?php
$path= '\\Iserver-s.com\iserver\2019_Plans\013036456-2018\PDF-DATA\ASSEMBLE\013036456-2018.pdf';

if (file_exists($path)) {
    $tbody .= '<td>DATA ON SERVER</td>';
} else {
    $tbody .= '<td>NO DATA</td>';
}
?>
```

It should display `DATA ON SERVER` on my table td if file exist.
But it always output `NO DATA` even if the file exist.

I'm thinking that it doesn't access files or dir outside the ftp server.
I'm currently using Notepad++ with Nppfttp plugin connected..

that's all we stored and access our website within our company.

this is the path where my php located :

```
ftp://appss5080/Ext/Qpd/Plan_Monitoring/index.php
```

and this is what I'am trying to access of check a file if exist(in my local C:)

```
C:/Users/ps5178/Desktop/6490700-2018-MISTAKE-10-18/6490700-201845.pdf
```

So, how can access files outside of it?

Comment: show the level of the file what you trying to execute. where it is located . Compare to `root` of your web `index.php` file

Comment: http://appStores5080/Monitoring/Plan_monitoring/index.php this is the url I'am using for my website system monitoring... It is on ftp.. if i tried $path = 'index,php' it output DATA ON SERVER.. because it's on same location in my url (or inside ftp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
// the server you wish to connect to - you can also use the server ip ex. 107.23.17.20
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";

// set up a connection to the server we chose or die and show an error
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");
ftp_login($conn_id,"ftpserver_username","ftpserver_password");
// check if a file exist
$path = "/SERVER_FOLDER/"; //the path where the file is located

$file = "file.html"; //the file you are looking for
$check_file_exist = $path.$file; //combine string for easy use

$contents_on_server = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path); //Returns an array of filenames from the specified directory on success or FALSE on error. 
// Test if file is in the ftp_nlist array
if (in_array($check_file_exist, $contents_on_server)) 
{
   echo "<br>";
   echo "I found ".$check_file_exist." in directory : ".$path;
}
else
{
   echo "<br>";
   echo $check_file_exist." not found in directory : ".$path;  
};

// output $contents_on_server, shows all the files it found, helps for debugging, you can use print_r() as well
var_dump($contents_on_server);

// remember to always close your ftp connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: I cannot use the current real path. My site in located inside ftp server. What am i trying is to check if files exist outside of it.. Example: In my C:/

Comment: I've also tried $path = 'file:///C:/Users/ps5178/Desktop/6490700-2018-MISTAKE-10-18/6490700-201845.pdf' ...  but still it says not exist..

Comment: I did changes for ftp

Comment: Based on my understanding on your code, it's only trying to check the file inside the ftp server.. but the path/ file that I need to check is on a shared folder and not inside the ftp server..

Comment: That is why i asked you to specify where exactly your file is located compare to folder what are you trying to search, you can simply use `../` to go up on 1 level from your current folder. That will give you the way to specify the path for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problem / solution

firts: Did you verify the permissions on the file?.

Second: Use ftp_get() (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php), 
it would be the most convenient.

Comment: My site is inside the ftp server.. What am i trying is to check the files outside of it.. like e.g In my C://

Comment: I'm almost sure it's a directory issue (it's not the absolute one). check for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852767/how-can-i-check-if-a-file-exists-on-a-remote-server-using-php

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your code in my local. which is working file. I have checked with my local file path.

I think you have a problem with your path. confirm that the path is correct or not.

And also check the file permission which should have 755 or 777.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$path = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\XSCAssets\idea\157406374721215421965dd24e83bf2e7.png';

if (file_exists($path)) {
    $tbody = '<td>DATA ON SERVER</td>';
} else {
    $tbody = '<td>NO DATA</td>';
}
echo $tbody;
?>
```

Comment: note that i'm using ftp server for my site and not on the htdocs. I also tried to access local file on my C:\ but still no luck...